# Is there a way to remove a migration added to sqitch?

Tags: sqitch

In sqitch there is the ADD command to add a new migration.
Is there any command to remove that ADDITION?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I do it:

1. revert the change from the database.
2. Remove it manually from the plan or plan files
3. Remove manually the scripts in deploy/, verify/ and revert/

My cases have been simple, so the above works without issue. I could see complications if the change you are trying to remove is required by other changes down stream. In that situation or as alternative to above I would look at creating a change that reverses the effect of the change you are trying to undo.